# Узнать количество ядер процессора VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

Добрый день! Есть ли в VBS такая функция (или метод) которая бы позволила мне увидеть количество ядер процессора? То есть: нужен код, который определит кол-во ядер процессора. То есть `physicalCoreAmount` – должно равняться кол-ву ядер процессора.  Искал до этого в Гугле, но там либо что-то не то, либо ответы ещё прямиком из мезозоя. Спасибо за помощь!

```vbscript
Option Explicit 

Dim runBatch, coreAmount, physicalCoreAmount
Rem physicalCoreAmount – должно равняться кол-ву ядер процессора
Set runBatch = CreateObject(WSCript.shell)

Do
coreAmount = inputBox("Укажите кол-во ядер (Set your amount of cores)", "Укажите колличество ядер")
If coreAmount = "" then
  msgbox "Введите количество ядер!",vbOkOnly + vbCritical,"Ошибка"
Else If not IsNumeric(coreAmount) then
  msgbox "Введите числовое значение!",vbOkOnly + vbCritical,"Ошибка"
Else If InStr(1, coreAmount, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 or InStr(1, coreAmount, ",", vbTextCompare) > 0  then
  msgbox "Введите числовое значение без точки или запятой!",vbOkOnly + vbCritical,"Ошибка"
Else If coreAmount > physicalCoreAmount then
  msgbox "Введите верное количество ядер. Не более" + physicalCoreAmount + ".",vbOkOnly + vbCritical,"Ошибка"
Else
  exit do   
Loop
```

Comment: Не популярная этот VBScript тема 

Comment: Спросите у пользовате...а, вы уже.

Comment: @Lyth  Что? Не понял вопроса.  То есть я не понял.

Comment: Прошу прощения за странное чувство юмора, в моём комментарии не хватало смайлика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Windows есть подсистема менеджмента, к которой можно обратиться (иногда даже без прав администратора). Этот код перечисляет все процессоры (их может быть несколько, особенно на серверных машинах) и суммирует количество ядер в них:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", _
                                      wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

coreCount = 0
For Each objItem In colItems
    coreCount = coreCount + objItem.NumberOfCores
Next

WScript.Echo "Всего ядер: " & coreCount
```

Comment: Секунду, проверю.

Comment: Отлично работает, спасибо.